# Multi Tier Platform will not retrieve database connection string

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Using Visual Studio 2010 and C#: I am developing a multi tier application.  Client will talk to WCF service platform -> WCF talks to Business Layer -> Business Layer talks to Database access layer.  I'm developing these from bottom up. 
From a Windows application I call the Business Layer, which calls the Database Access Layer works just fine.

When I add the WCF Service layer - my WCF test will call the service, which calls the business layer, which calls the database access layer. That is where the problem happens.  The first step is to get the Connection String.  When called from WCF I get: Trusted_Connection=yes; Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; When called from any other base (like the Winform project - without WCF) it gets the values from the config file and works.

I'm sure it is a simple configuration I am missing, but I have not been able to find it yet.  I would appreciate any guidance you may be able to offer.

Bill

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF service, IIS?

Comment: Is your connection string coming from your Web.config (or App.config)?  How are you generating your connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have your connection string values in the Web.config file for your WCF service.  Since the business and data layers are being called from the WCF service, the config values will need to originate in the WCF Web.config.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I got pulled off on another project and between that and the holidays - have been very slow getting back to this issue. The service is hosted on IIS, calls a business layer dll which in turn calls a Database access layer dll.  The database access layer is pulling the connection string from it's App.Config file.  I managed to get this working by adding the business layer and DB access layer both to the WCF project, but I am not absolutely confident that was the proper resolution.   Once again, thanks for your help.